# wordpress plugin hide from admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress,i am willing to only hide some wordpress installed plugin from admin panel or called or work through from my `theme-function.php`,is possible?

Comment: Are you sure you should be hiding a plugin? If you have code which you wish to run all the time i would suggest looking into MU Plugins - https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69338164/7186739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bellow code in your function.php file

```
<?php
add_filter('all_plugins', 'hide_plugins');

function hide_plugins($plugins) {
    unset($plugins['akismet/akismet.php']);
    //unset($plugins['plugin-dir-name/plugin-file.php']);
    return $plugins;
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest using it as a `mu-plugin`.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to hide all plugins then try this code in functions.php file

```
add_filter('all_plugins', '__return_empty_array');
```

If you like to hide specific plugin then try this code in functions.php file

```
add_filter('all_plugins', 'hide_plugins');

function hide_plugins($plugins) {
    unset($plugins['pods/init.php']); 
    //unset($plugins['plugin-folder-name/plugin-file.php']);
    return $plugins;
}
```

If you like to hide multiple plugins then try this code in functions.php file

```
add_filter('all_plugins', 'hide_plugins');

function hide_plugins($plugins) {
    unset($plugins['pods/init.php']);
    unset($plugins['akismet/akismet.php']); 
    //unset($plugins['plugin-folder-name/plugin-file.php']);
    return $plugins;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide sensitive data in WordPress like login page ,plugins and theme you can use Hide My WP Ghost – Security Plugin.